# Minimum-cost efficient solution to the circulation problem

Tags: open-source, library, graphs

I must solve some minimum-cost circulation problem (as described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_problem)) in a efficient way.
Unfortunately I have not found many implementations.

I found [LEMMON](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) that I believe solves it, but I found the documentation confusing and I would prefer it not to be written on C (I intend to inspect the code), or at the very least to have bindings to other languages.

So I would like to ask for other libraries that solve this problem. I would want:

- written in Java, Python, MATLAB or R
- good documentation
- using efficient strong polynomial time algorithm
- open source